# Android, AOSP tree, external project (ffmpeg) is built for AMD64

Tags: android, ffmpeg, cross-compiling

I'm trying to build [ffmpeg4android](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/) on current AOSP tree (from /external), which is lunch-configured to aosp_arm-eng and set to `PLATFORM_VERSION=4.2`.

Resulting files are generated for `AMD64` (host native) architecture, even though the major rest of tree is built (as expected) `ARM`:

> readelf -a android/aosp_arm-eng/ffplay|egrep "Class:|Machine:"
>   Class:                             ELF64   Machine:
>   Advanced Micro Devices X86-64

versus

> readelf -a
>   aosp/out/target/product/generic/symbols/system/lib/libril.so | egrep "Class:|Machine:"
>
> Class:                             ELF32
>   Machine:                           ARM

---

I will probably switch to other ways of getting `ffmpeg-arm` (presumably the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812827/build-ffmpeg-with-x264-for-android)); the reason of asking this question is to understand, at which build stage does cross-compilation environment breaks.

Comment: First candidate: if C compiler cannot create executable files, then a fallback to default 'gcc' happens. (which can be hardly noticeable in large logs)

Comment: `ffplay` is a really bad example: build ffmpeg4android does not build  it for Android.